# array checkbox.checked javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

```
<form id="form1" name="form_check" method="post" action="">
<p align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="3"></p> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="check_all()">
<script>
function check_all(){
    checkedBox="x"
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('role[]').length;i++){
        if(document.getElementsByName('role[i]').checked == true){
            checkedBox="y"
            break // No need to check the rest since only one can be checked.
        }
    }
    if(checkBox == "x"){
        alert("Checkbox not checked")
    }
}
</script>
```

I have written the code above to check is the checkboxes are checked. It doesn't execute the if statement in the JavaScript area. I am unable to get a output.
in JSfiddle when iam trying to execute this script i get this error :

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x22c58d0>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x25563d0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x22c58d0>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x2556cd0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

This script worked for me:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('role[]');

checkedBox = "x";
for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        //alert("checked: " + radios[i].value);
        checkedBox = "y";
        break; // No need to check the rest since only one can be checked.
    }
}
```

Comment: *"// No need to check the rest since only one can be checked"* - if that's the case why aren't you using radio buttons?

Comment: i wanted to check if users have checked atleast one checkbox from the multiple once..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You've declared a variable `checkedBox` but in the `if` condition you're using `checkBox`
- `document.getElementsByName('role[i]')` will be null since there's no matching element. (*`document.getElementsByName('role[' + i + ']')` will be also be null for the same reason.*)

What you actually need to use is

```
document.getElementsByName('role[]')[i].checked.
```

But accessing the `DOM` in loops like this is not a good practice, it's better to store the htmlCollection in a variable.

So after all your code should look like

```
function check_all() {
 checkedBox = "x";
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('role[]');
 for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if ( checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkedBox = "y"
        break // No need to check the rest since only one can be checked.
    }
 }
 if (checkedBox == "x") {
    alert("Checkbox not checked");
    return false;
 }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/S5Luh/)

*Side notes:*

- IMHO, it's a good practice to use `boolean` values for flags for better readability understandability than `x`, `y` etc...
- You aren't closing the `<form>` tag in the shared code...

Comment: thanks @Tilwin Joy you script worked for me with javascript, i have pasted above..

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want the `i` not be a literal i:

`if(document.getElementsByName('role[' + i + ']').checked == true){`

You can always use `console.log` as a debugging aid to find these kinds of errors.

Comment: thanks, now its executing the if loop but not going inside. showing as not check when i have already checked checkboxes.